# the mappers execute sequentially not parallelly

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, task, mapper, slave

Hello i have i problem with the times of executinon of mappers:
well finally i succeed to do that:
read 2 file inputs :one file per mapper and i add this property
`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum =1` to `mapred-site.xml` :
and this work good for me so the finale result:
 one file per mapper and one mapper per node .
problem that when i look to master:50030 i find that the mappers (2 mappers one that execute in master and the other in slave) execute sequentially not parallelly why?how i fix this problem?

Comment: noo i am testing in 2 nodes (one master and slave and the second is a slave)

Comment: @axiom i use also Distributed Cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/mapred-default.html), `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` set the maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.

You should set this parameter to a value greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you very much i will modify that...what is the property that set the number of tasks per node?or i will obtain that automatically in my program

Comment: i mean one map per node ...i use WholeFileInputFormat